# Задача из книги "Начинаем программировать на Пайтон" Том Гэддис

Tags: python, python-3.x

После ответа "Да" код выдает "отлично", но перед этим выдает предыдущие условие.
Как это исправить ?
Да и вообще хотелось бы увидеть другие варианты решения этой задачи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
a1 = "Перезагрузите компьютер и попробуйте подключиться"
a2 = "Перезагрузите маршрутизатор и попробуйте еще раз"
a3 = "Убедитесь, что кабели в исправны"
a4 = "Переместите маршрутизатор на новое место."
a5 = "Замените роутер, скорее всего он неисправен."
a6 = "Отлично"
sps = ["нет"]
if a in sps:
    print()
    print(a1)
    print()
if a in sps:
    a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
    print()
    print(a2)
    print()
if a in sps:
    a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
    print()
    print(a3)
    print()
if a in sps:
    a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
    print()
    print(a4)
    print()
if a in sps:
    a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
    print()
    print(a5)
else:
    if a == "да":
        print(a6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*После ответа "Да" код выдает "отлично", но перед этим выдает предыдущие условие.*  -  ну, во-первых, не предыдущее, а последующее, и не условие, а указание. Хоть посмотрите внимательно, что делает ваше программа до того, как вопросы задавать.
Во-вторых, ваша задача решается вот так:

```
arr0=["Перезагрузите компьютер и попробуйте подключиться",
     "Перезагрузите маршрутизатор и попробуйте еще раз",
     "Убедитесь, что кабели в исправны",
     "Переместите маршрутизатор на новое место.",
     "Замените роутер, скорее всего он неисправен."]

for i,qu in enumerate(arr0):
    a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
    if a=='да':
        print ('Отлично')
        break
    else: 
       print(arr0[i])
```

По просьбе ТС и по замечанию уважаемого **Stanislav Volodarskiy**  тот-же код без  enumerate:

```
for qu in arr0:
        a = input("Исправили проблему? ")
        if a=='да':
            print ('Отлично')
            break
        else: 
           print(qu)
```

Comment: `arr0[i]` -> `qu`. `enumerate` не нужен.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Как всегда соглашусь. Можно и как вы предлагаете. Просто "разжевал" ответ до последней крошки.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо большое за ваше решение, но проблема в том, что я только начал изучать питон, и еще не знаю такую функцию, как "enumerate".
Вот сижу и пытаюсь досконально понять ваш код. 
В частности не  понимаю что за переменная "qu" и зачем она.
Могли бы вы дать объяснение, если вас это не затруднит?
Плюс к этому хотелось бы решение не используя даже список, так как по этой книге, эта задача находится еще до темы со списками, кортежами и словарями, то есть предполагает самое примитивное решение, по типу моего.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: "решение, по типу моего"  - так у вас не решение, потому-как код работает неправильно! И написан он так как вам хочется, а не по предложенному алгоритму. Вот, возьмите алгоритм, который у вас приведен и напишите код вТОЧНОМ ему соответствии. И вот тогда у вас будет решение "по типу вашего" но правильное..

Comment: Потому я сюда и написал, я просто не понимал, как это сделать)
Сейчас, благодаря вам, понял, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.

```
recomendations = [
    "Перезагрузите компьютер и попробуйте подключиться",
    "Перезагрузите маршрутизатор и попробуйте еще раз",
    "Убедитесь, что кабели в исправны",
    "Переместите маршрутизатор на новое место.",
    "Замените роутер, скорее всего он неисправен.",
]

i = 0
while i < len(recomendations):
    print(recomendations[i])
    match input("Исправили проблему? "):
        case 'n'|'no'|'нет':
            i += 1
        case 'y'|'yes'|'да':
            print('Отлично')
            break
        case _:
            print('Дайте ответ: да(y,yes) или нет(n,no)')
else:
    print('Жаль, что не смогли помочь.')
```